# How to get the members of a Facebook Friendlist?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the facebook API it is easy to request all friendlists of a user.
But how can i get the members of a friendlist?

The API-Documentation says, the request URL would be "{friend-list-id}/members", but it returns an empty data-result.

Comment: You can't. It is not possible in API v2.0 and later to get members of a friends list

Comment: Shall this be true? They have a documentation for the endpoint:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/members

Comment: That is true. File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs so we update the documentation

Comment: @WizKid: In 2012 i built selectr.me as a Facebook Friendlist Manager. Does your comment mean i can shutdown this service? It just works for me and other users, but there are plenty of users which reports bugs to me that it doesnt work for them. I think, for "old" users the api still works but not for newer ones. Can you agree or disagree?

Comment: For old users it will work until 4/30/2015. After that all users are upgraded to v2.0 which will return empty

Comment: That's really a pitty...